# Read only privileges to records in salesforce

Tags: salesforce

I have to make a field read only after user has entered value in salesforce so that even that particular user cannot change the value once its entered. How could i achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

To my knowledge, Salesforce does not have a "allow this field to be set only once" setting. Simplest way would probably be a validation rule that only throws an error when the field is changed and the field's previous value wasn't blank, something like:

```
AND(
    ISCHANGED(SomeField__c),
    NOT(ISBLANK(PRIORVALUE(SomeField__c)))
)
```

Or for a picklist:

```
AND(
    ISCHANGED(SomeField__c),
    NOT(ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(SomeField__c), ''))
)
```